# Unable to run nagios, it says command not found?

Tags: nagios

Just installed nagios core 4.1.1 as per:
https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/Installing_Nagios_Core_From_Source.pdf#_ga=1.246667780.1471708323.1465398477

My previous version was working in essence I could access it through apache. It was not configured and I deleted it left and right as I could not find any good documentation to uninstall it.

I have definitely followed the steps above but when I boot in and sudo to root, for nagios command I get the following.

```
[root@agent2 init.d]# nagios
-bash: nagios: command not found
[root@agent2 init.d]#
```

User nagios exist

```
[root@agent2 init.d]# cat /etc/passwd|grep nagios
nagios:x:495:492::/var/spool/nagios:/sbin/nologin
[root@agent2 init.d]#
```

No idea where is my user nagios admin which I did create with htppasswd command.

```
[root@agent2 init.d]# cat /etc/passwd|grep -i nagiosadmin
[root@agent2 init.d]# pwd
/etc/init.d
[root@agent2 init.d]# ./nagios status
nagios (pid 3264) is running...
[root@agent2 init.d]#
```

But when I try to access the nagios through http://localhost/nagios, I don't seems to have any luck.

What is annoying is when I run command locate nagios there is still something on system from nagios 3.5.1
The list is too big to paste here but I need some help to have nagios accessible through UI

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Well I don't think nagios is a command, rather it's a service, which is why it's in `/etc/init.d`.  You ran `service nagios status`, and it seems to be running fine.  How about apache2?  Make sure that's running as well.  Once you do that, and there are still problems, post more clues.  What are you seeing in your browser when you visit http://localhost/nagios?  Look through logs and post what you see, namely the apache or nagios logs.  Locate your `nagios.cfg` config file to see where nagios logs are logged to, and look there.  Post any clues and I'll try to help.

Comment: Well interesting thing is I can use "service nagios status" only after I start nagios by going to /etc/init.d. This is version 4.1.1, previous version binary was in my path so I could do service nagios status from anywhere.
Good point you made , mine is CentOS and htppd was not running therefore I was not able to access it.
Still two issues:
1. I can access it via http://localhost.nagios but not http://<IP>/nagios
2. It complains about 8 critical service problem but what I see is there are no scripts under libexec.

Comment: [root@agent2 libexec]# ls
eventhandlers
check_users, check_load etc no script for that...

Where are these scripts gone if my installation was successful enough ?

Comment: Good news is nagios is up and running. Aparat from httpd daemon not running, plugin installation was also missing. I thought we don't need plugin for Nagios Server.

My only question is how access nagios with http://<unix server ip>/nagios as apart from localhost I would like to have it access with IP as well or even better with hostname

Comment: hm, well that's good news overall.  So regarding your last question about not being able to visit via IP, are you trying to access `http://<unix server ip>/nagios` from localhost or from another machine?  Check if you can ping the hostname, and note the ip that it resolves to.  Obviously if you can't ping, there's no connection.  I would post your new question in serverfault and see if the guys there can help out.

Comment: Actually I forgot to update as I was so engrossed in study. I could get it working.I can get inside the VM but not outside when in fact the port 80 is open. I cannot get even get to apache of that unix server from host.